# Why does my iPhone5 playing songs through my Apple TV times out after three songs?

Tags: itunes, wifi, music, appletv, iphone

I want to play songs on my Apple TV from my iPhone5 running 8.1. After about three songs, it stops playing (tested three times). Is there any possible explanation for this?

My question is: **Why does my iPhone5 playing songs through my Apple TV times out after three songs?**

--

EDIT:
Router: Netcomm NB9WMAXX

Terminology: I'm calling it 'timing out'. Perhaps a more correct term would be 'arbitrarily stopping' - except that we can repeat the behaviour multiple times at roughly the same time period.

Error: seeing no error on either device

Library: Stored on iphone

Network usage: Nothing else was using the network at this time

Comment: The first questions that come to my mind are how do you know it's "timing out" or are you just calling the issue timing out?  Are you seeing an error message on either device?  What is the EXACT error you are seeing?  Is the library actually stored on the iPhone or is the library actually on a 3rd device?  What else is using the network? How old is the router? Specifically is the router old and not optimized for streaming protocols?

Comment: One thought is that 3 songs is about 10 minutes.  Can you try it with a longer song or 2, to see if it's exactly 10 minutes?  Might be a sleep setting on the phone or ATV.

Answer (score -2):

Try connect ur app TV with Ethernet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would solve the problem?